# ImageView in a customImageViewCell in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have one small issue that I can't seem to resolve since I'm a beginner in Swift.
I have tableView with a customTableViewCell, which contains customImageView amongst other things. I'm trying to change the customImageView's image by tapping on the image and than via segue, select the new image from another viewController. Everything work fine, apart from new selected image always appearing in the first tableView row, regardless of which imageView I tapped (there are many rows with each having its own image in the customImageView). I understand I have to somehow dedicate indexPath to the imageView of desired customTableViewCell, but that where the problem lies. I don't know how to do that. By tapping only on the imageView, I'm not selecting the actual row, thus, I don't have indexPath.row available for the imageView to call upon. How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance,
Dusan

Here's a bit of code that might shine some light

```
var imageChanged = false
var selectedImage = UIImage()

func imageTapped(sender: UIImageView) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Image Change", message: "Would you like to change the image?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showNewLogoImages", sender: self)
        self.imageChanged = true
        })

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped))

    cell.customImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

    if imageChanged == true {
        cell.customImageView.image = selectedImage
        imageChanged = false

    } else {
        cell.customImageView.image = UIImage(named: "noImage")
        for logo in logos {
        if cell.cellTitle.text!.lowercaseString.containsString(logo) {
        cell.customImageView.image = UIImage(named: logo)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using true/false to mark that the image has changed, how about saving the image view that was tapped as `UIImageView?`?  Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can check whether there's a selected view and whether it matches the image view of the current cell.

Comment: Thats an interesting concept I wasn't aware of. Let me try that. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, I just realized, I don't know how to check if there's a selected view :(

Comment: By "selected view" I meant whether you had gone through the `imageTapped` logic and saved the sender.  (i.e. selected it to be changed)

Comment: Yes, I figured out what you meant, but still having some issues with uncaught exceptions. Im trying to make it work still. Thanks for you input

Comment: Simply cannot figure this one out, I always get exceptions like this one : [UITapGestureRecognizer image]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13f58e260, when I try to compare tapped and customCell images within cellForRowAtIndexPath.